# Regular expression to allow certain characters and disable a few others

Tags: regex

I have to write a regular expression which allows alphabets and numbers, but does not permit characters like / and ? . Can someone help me out on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which regex flavor? Do you consider `à`, `ñ` or `Щ` to be letters and `۳` or `۸` to be numbers?

Comment: Either enumerate what you do want to allow, or what you want to disallow. We can't help you (and you cannot solve this yourself, either) without this clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does what you have asked for:

```
^(?!.*(/|\?))[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

It simply matches only on input that is comprised solely of letters and/or numbers, plus it does a negative lookahead to make sure no `/` or `?` are present.

To exclude *more* special chars, just add them to the look ahead, for example to also exclude `@` use this `(?!.*(/|\?|@))` (the `?` needs escaping with a backslash `\`)

Comment: I do not wish to block all of the special characters. Just a certain number, like ? and / to mention a couple.

Comment: OK - edited to do a negative lookahead to exclude certain special chars

Comment: I tested this expression, It does block the required characters but it doesnt seem to permit alphanumeric characters as well.....

Comment: I am confused about when to escape characters in regex. For e.g. in the negative lookahead, I expected that you need to escape `/` just like you escaped `?`.

Comment: @WebUser the slash `/` has no special meaning in any flavour of regex. However, some languages (such as JavaScript) use the slash to *delimit* regex (like quotes around a string), and in such cases you would need to escape them just as you escape literal quotes in a string, by that’s not a regex escape, it’s a language literal escape - nothing to do with regex.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to allow more than just ASCII letters and numbers (and your regex flavor supports Unicode), you can use

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta character `\w` matches alphanumerics which means all numbers, ASCII letters and underscore (`_`).

Answer (score 0):

you could try to concentrate on characters that you dont want to allow if that list is more clear than allowed one:

```
^[^\?\/\s\(\)]+$
```

Fill [] with more characters that you dont like